# bat file start open chrome chrome://downloads/

Tags: google-chrome, batch-file

I am trying to open an instance of chrome to the download manager chrome flag. But it's not liking me whatsoever. URL's will work perfectly fine so I know that the chrome flag is not a url so how would we open this part of chrome
`chrome://downloads/`

```
start /D "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application" chrome.exe --new-window "chrome://downloads/"
```

Comment: Chrome ignores `chrome://` urls on command line.

Comment: So... that doesn't help that much, is it not possible or do we just write downloads?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not possible.

Look at [StartupBrowserCreator::GetURLsFromCommandLine](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/chrome/browser/ui/startup/startup_browser_creator.cc&sq=package:chromium&l=564&rcl=1445657257) in the Chromium source code:

```cpp
      if (policy->IsWebSafeScheme(url.scheme()) ||
          url.SchemeIs(url::kFileScheme) ||
#if defined(OS_CHROMEOS)
          // In ChromeOS, allow any settings page to be specified on the command
          // line. See ExistingUserController::OnLoginSuccess.
          (url.spec().find(chrome::kChromeUISettingsURL) == 0) ||
#else
          ((url.spec().find(std::string(chrome::kChromeUISettingsURL) +
                            chrome::kResetProfileSettingsSubPage) == 0)) ||
#endif
          (url.spec().compare(url::kAboutBlankURL) == 0)) {
        urls.push_back(url);
      }
```

- In ChromeOS, any `chrome://settings` page may be specified on the command line
- On other platforms only `chrome://settings/resetProfileSettings` is allowed.
- Always allowed are all [web-safe schemes](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/content/browser/child_process_security_policy_impl.cc&sq=package:chromium&l=297&rcl=1445657257) `http://`, `https://`, `ftp://`, `data:`, `feed`, `blob:`,
  real file paths like `c:\something.html` and `about:blank`.

So all `chrome://` urls are ignored on the command line with the exception mentioned above.

Comment: Thank you that's an answer! I appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code you can use:

#### Batch File:

```
start https://www.google.com/
timeout /t 10
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "{c}{h}{r}{o}{m}{e}{:}{/}{/}{d}{o}{w}{n}{l}{o}{a}{d}{s}{/}"
%SendKeys% "{ENTER}"
```